# Accessing Resource class fields in PostProcessInterceptor?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, jax-rs, resteasy

I have a resource class as

```
@Path("secure")
@RequestScoped
// @SecurityChecked
public class SecureResource {

    @Context
    private HttpServletRequest request;

    @GET
    @SecurityChecked
    public Response getUser() {
        return Response.ok("authenticated successfully!").build();
    }

    @POST
    public Response login(@FormParam("user") @Nonnull final String user,
                          @FormParam("password") @Nonnull final String password) {
        final String authToken = TokenUtils.createToken(user);
        return Response.ok().header(AUTH_TOKEN, authToken).build();
    }

    @PUT
    public Response updateUser() {
        return Response.ok("updating user").build();
    }
}
```

and I have a `PostProcessInterceptor` where I would like to access the `request` of header class

```
@Interceptor
@Provider
@ServerInterceptor
@SecurityChecked
public class SecurityCheckInterceptor implements PostProcessInterceptor {
    private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile(":");
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecurityCheckInterceptor.class);
    @Override
    public void postProcess(final ServerResponse response) {
        // access the Resource class request object

    }
}
```

I am not sure how can I access the request object here

Please help

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to access request in PostProcessInterceptor? Are you sure you cant use

```
public static class MyInterceptor implements PreProcessInterceptor{
...
@Override
public ServerResponse preProcess(HttpRequest request, ResourceMethod method){...}
}
```

here?

Comment: Yes, because, request has `Headers` and I need to access those to create a new Header before the response is sent. Does it makes sense?

Comment: im not familiar with this api. Maybe take a look at http://www.mastertheboss.com/resteasy/resteasy-interceptors-tutorial/page-2 where respone object is manually created in preProcess handler - new Headers<Object>() is passed. Probably you should be able to add header there.